# Is “in a greater scale” grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Say the facts are

- Method A produces score of 101.
- Method B produces score of 102.

when using data set 1, but when using data set 2:

- Method A produces score of 100.
- Method B produces score of 1000.

Method B is better than Method A in both datasets; what I want to say is Method B performed much better with dataset 2.

Is the following sentence correct?

> Method B outperforms Method A in a greater scale in dataset 2 compared to dataset 1.

Comment: Would you please replace the *'->'* with words in your question? It's not at all clear what you mean.  Do you mean that method *A* *receives a rating of 101*, or *produces a result of 101*?  Also 101 is less than 102 but 1000 is greater than 100 so in data set *A*, method *A* does not outperform *B* at all.

Comment: @Jim I have edited the question

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

> Method B, which performs *little better* than A with dataset #1, outperforms A *by a far greater margin* with dataset #2.

Comment: I have edited the question, could you kindly take a look again? thanks.

Comment: @william007: I've edited the answer accordingly. It's still the case that idiomatically you'd talk about *by a greater margin* (or *more decisively*, etc.) rather than *[on] a greater scale*, which has different connotations. Note that we don't normally speak of anything being ***in** a greater scale*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

> Method *B* outperforms Method *A* ***to a greater degree*** for Dataset 2 than it does for Dataset 1.